# Meaning of colon

Tags: c++

I was reading up on "openFrameworks" and I found a peace of code where I fail to understand the meaning of a colon, i.e. directly behind ofApp

```
void ofApp:setup(){
    mySound.load("fileName.mp3");
}
```

See [openFramework site](https://openframeworks.cc/learning/04_sound/play_a_sound/) for original.

Could anybody explain to me what the meaning of that is?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a typo. `:` should be `::`. You can see it being correct in the fourth code block of the linked examples, while the previous two were, presumably, copy-pasted with the same error.

It may, however, be confused as a [*label*](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/statements#Labels), but a label cannot be placed in such contexts.